# How can I find the maximum weight between any two nodes in an undirected graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

This is referring to not the length of the path, but the sum of the weights of the path traversed. I am getting confused by the variety of algorithms out there.

Suppose that for a graph represented by a dictionary of tuple keys and integer values, my simple idea is to check each pair of nodes to see which nodes connect and simply add up the maximum weight seen so far. I don't know of a better starting point than this.

Comment: are you looking for the longest path? Then that's NP-complete. Or is your graph double-labeled with cost and length, and you always consider the shortest path? If so, what happens if the shortest path isn't unique?

Comment: I'm not looking for the longest path, but rather the path where the weights when summed up gives the maximum value.

Comment: Call your weights "length", and you're down to a well known NP-hard problem.

Comment: Do you know where I can further read up on this NP hard problem? I interpreted length as the number of edges and not the values of the weight. e.g. one edge with value 8 has overall higher weight value than 2 edges with of values 2,3 respectively.

Comment: If you only talk about shortest paths, what happens if there are multiple paths of the same length, as is a common occurrence in unlabeled graphs?

Comment: **Length** of a path in a graph is typically *not* the number of edges in the path, but rather the sum of the "weights" (lengths) of each edge in the path. Finding the longest path is NP-Complete in the general sense as mentioned above. Are there any special properties to your data that might help; e.g. directed/undirected, cyclic/acyclic, actually a tree? More information about the data might help us help you.

Comment: The graph is undirected with cyclic connections in some part and not a tree.